# google.auth._default DEBUG: Checking for service account

Tags: gcloud, service-accounts

I have got a project using

> GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

with a service account json file

I have successfully done

```
gcloud auth login
```

as well as

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

I removed GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as well as tried with giving some dummy value then run the project still this is looking for GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

I am not able to see from where its searching GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS service account json file.

I think if the email using for gcloud auth login has all the permissions it should work.. but its not working and searching that json file

Any help highly appreciated...

*UPDATE*
I tried using  below command

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json
```

to set the json file of gcloud auth login

still throwing error

> [google.auth._default] DEBUG: Explicit credentials path
> /Users/xxx/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json is the
> same as Cloud SDK credentials path, fall back to Cloud SDK credentials

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. What was the original error? If you wish to disable ADC, on Linux, you can `unset GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. The error you include appears to be a consequence of setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/application_default_credentials.json`. You should not set (`unset`) the variable if you wish to use the credentials created by `gcloud auth application-default login`. That all said, you should use a Service Account rather than credentials created by `gcloud auth application-default login`.

Comment: @DazWilkin, I want to use the credentials created by gcloud auth application-default login for any api... I don't want to use any other service account